# How to always scroll to bottom?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I want the scroll scroll down to the bottom when add some text to the div.
This is my code. I can't find why it's not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script>
            window.onload = () => {
                const add = document.getElementById('add');
                const c = document.getElementById('content');
                add.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    c.innerHTML += '<p>aaaaa</p>';
                    c.scrollTop = c.scrollHeight;
                });
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="add">add</button>
        <div id="content">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) method.

So instead of `c.scrollTop = c.scrollHeight;` just do `c.scrollIntoView(false);`.

The solution you tried (`c.scrollTop = c.scrollHeight;`) does not work because you append elements into the div dynamically. I mean such solution is a one-time deal. If you change the content, you will have to re-execute scrolling.

Besides that, you can do the following trick using [`window.scrollTo`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp) method:

```
window.scrollTo(0, c.scrollHeight);
```

Comment: @user3130007 Yeah, and it's pretty useful.

Answer (score 1):

if You want to scroll down, You must use this:

```
window.scrollTo(0,c.scrollHeight);
```

Comment: You mean use `window.scrollTo(c.scrollHeight, 0);` instead of `c.scrollTop = c.scrollHeight;`?

Comment: @user3130007 I believe, he means that. But arguments should be passed vice versa: `window.scrollTo(0, c.scrollHeight);`

Comment: @user3130007 Cool :) I hope you read my answer to understand why your first solution is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Use `scrollIntoView()` instead of `scrollTop` & `scrollHeight` and don't forget to fix position the button otherwise it you'll constantly have to scroll up to continue.

Comment: Thanks for your tips